# How to call list of updatable

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

I have an interface, 'Updatable' which contains an 'update' method. I want to have a list of instances of this interface but am unsure how to name it. Is there a plural form of updatable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, adjectives are invariable in English (unlike French for instance).

Why not simply name your collection as: `updatableElements` or `updatableList`.